# Set up the variable for URL link in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion-11

How to set up a variable on the root directory for the url link in ColdFusion?

I set up the variable on the root directory for the url link, appweb\instance.cfm:

```
<CFSCRIPT>
 ...
 ...     
  Application.MainLink = "http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.html";

</CFSCRIPT>
```

I have a file under appweb/costsharing/footer.cfm to use the variable for url link, but it doesn't work.

```
<br />
<br />
<div align="center">
<b>Need Help?  Visit the <a href="#Application.MainLink#" target=_blank>Cost    Sharing Help</a></b>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<CFInclude Template="../OnRequestEnd.cfm">

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: elaborate your question?? **set up a variable on the root directory** are you trying to call your file from other directory ?

Comment: Not call this file, but I need to reference the variable from the subdirectory.

Comment: you need to reference `#Application.MainLink#" ` ??  any error ?

Comment: Yes, I need use the variable 'Application.MainLink' on subdirectory. When I click on 'Cost Sharing Help',  it doesn't go to http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.cfm. It points to http://appweb/costsharing/#Application.Mainlink#

Comment: how come it will go on  "ucdavis.edu/index.cfm' if you are setting ` Application.MainLink = "http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.html";` it should go "http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.html" as you are defining.

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo.  it should go '../index.html'.

Comment: its fine did you check the answer ??

Answer (score 1):

You can define.

```
<cfset Application.MainLink = "http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.html">
OR 
<cfset Application.MainLink = "http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.cfm">
```

If you want to point any sub-directory you can define in your application.cfc  root directory for example:

```
<cfset application.rootDir = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) />
```

In your code you can use:

```
#application.rootDir#/appweb/costsharing/index.cfm
```

USE this for link

`<a href="<cfoutput>#Application.MainLink#</cfoutput>" target=_blank>Cost Sharing Help</a>`

Comment: It doesn't go to http://www.ucdavis.edu/index.html.  What is the right code should be used in here for href?  <a href="#Application.MainLink#" target=_blank>Cost  Sharing Help</a>

Comment: Just Updated answer your not putting <cfoutput>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, for some reason beyond my understanding you need to put http:// in front. I am aware of the late response but I am doing this for future people that will have the same issue. So this can be used:

```
<a href="http://#Application.MainLink#" target=_blank>
```